# How to add a Web Service to a Delphi 2006 app?

Tags: web-services, delphi, soap

I have an application developed with Delphi 2006 using Indy 10. Does anyone know how to add the executable file a WebService feature so users can interact with it via SOAP? I've seen that the examples provided by Delphi need to have Indy 9, and since our application depends on Indy 10, going back to 9 is not an option, and unfortunately I haven't seen any other packages to provide this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the current release 10.5.7 of Indy (Tiburon branch) I sucessfully used this article to write a simple stand alone SOAP Server with Delphi 2009:

http://www.digicoast.com/delphi_soap_standalone.html

It should work fine with Delphi 2006 too (I am using the Indy 10 Tiburon branch even in Delphi 6).

The SOAP service can be consumed with Java (JAX-RPC) web clients, but I have not tested all possible datatypes.

Comment: Hi, thank for the link, but I'm having a problem. The default wizard creates a project which uses SockApp, and that unit seems to have been compiled only for Indy9. How did you overcome this issue? Thanks!

Comment: I managed to solve it by removing the SockApp references and changing some of the code from Indy10. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What if you encapsulated your logic into an Apache module (you will end up with a TWebModule) and serve it using Apache?

Answer (score 0):

I use remobjects sdk for this.  IIRC it works with both Indy 9 and 10.  Might be a bit expensive for you though.  http://www.remobjectssdk.com/